# Is there a legal way for people to elect other person as a president

Tags: united-states, constitution, donald-trump, hillary-clinton

Assume that in a few days to US residential election day, US people informed that Trump and Clinton [are liars](http://europe.newsweek.com/history-donald-trump-bill-clinton-friendship-464360?rm=eu),
[image]

And assume that this confirmed and the popularity of both reach to 10%.
Is there a legal way for people to elect other person as a president?

Comment: You could always try to convince enough people to vote for Gary Johnson. If opinions about the top 2 fall far enough, he may actually have a shot

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There's more than two candidates on the ballot, as well as the option to write-in a choice.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  As always, minor candidates are running for president, and if any of them were to secure a majority, then they would legally be elected.  Alternatively, if no candidate secures a majority, then the House of Representatives gets to legally select any of the three candidates with the most electoral votes.

Comment: Not whoever they want. The House is limited to the three candidates with the most electoral votes, per the 12th Amendment.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the answer to reflect that.  What about the case where there are only two candidates who get electoral votes?

Comment: Then there are two choices. The Twelfth Amendment says the House chooses from "the persons having the highest numbers not exceeding three on the list of those voted for as President;" you have to have gotten at least one EV to be eligible.